# Why is Java not running on Apple Silicon?

Tags: java, apple-silicon

I just got a MacBook Pro with the new M1 chip. I'd like to use native Apple Silicon code wherever possible.

I have a Java-based command-line program running and I noticed that this `java` process in Activity Monitor is of type 'Intel'.

The process's path is `/usr/bin/java`, which is supposed to be a Universal binary:

```
$ file /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/java (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/java (for architecture arm64e):    Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

So why is it running in Intel mode, and how can I run it natively?

Comment: How does this Java application get started?

Comment: @nohillside I run it from the command line `/usr/bin/java blah_blah_blah.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/java` is not the Java runtime. It is a wrapper that will launch a Java runtime. You can determine which Java runtime/JDK you're actually using by examining `java --version`.

Java versions are typically installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. You can download an Apple Silicon native JRE/JDK and copy it to that location and remove existing ones to ensure this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ezekiel. So the only way to get an M1-native JDK is to download from a third party?

Comment: @bill Java always is 3rd party :-)

Comment: @Bill Yes, For M1 or Intel, Java must be downloaded manually. There exist JDK and JRE packages that provide native functionality, with the same install process as Intel JDK/JRE packages. There is no change to M1 here.

Comment: Any recommendations for which JRE to use?

Comment: @becko I usually use the Azul Zulu builds